Are "critique my Chinese handwriting" questions on topic? And if so, how to write them appropriately?
I've been learning how to write Chinese (by hand), but I'm not sure how to go about using this site to help me with that (if at all).  One particular issue I encounter is that I can't tell the difference between when something is an acceptable writing style, or when something is simply an error.
Question: Are "critique my Chinese handwriting" questions on topic?  And if so, how to write them appropriately?
If I write something, take a photo, and post it as a question, it seems inherently unhelpful for subsequent users.
I asked such a question here: Do characters like 司, 习, and 可 have different first strokes?  I tried to make it as generally useful as possible (not just "Am I writing 可 wrong?").

Update: I mean "writing" as in "handwriting".  Sorry about the ambiguity; I updated the question and title.

I assume you mean penmanship and not grammar or word choice. I think you're right to be worried about making the question too narrow if it's just "is this writing sample legible?"
However, if you had a more general question about stroke formation, I think that might be a reasonable question. Think about asking concrete, specific questions about problems that you have had several times.

If you only want to know whether what you writing is right or wrong,you just writing as the printed in the book,however,you mentioned criticize your writing,because there are 行书and草书。usually,you just writing 行书is ok.as for 行书，the little mistake will be ok,because it can be as a writing art .of course ,you can also sent your writing to my email ,let me criticize your writing zhangwaves@gmail.com
